# How to close a p:messages through a button?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

For primefaces messages, here is an example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/messages.jsf.

In this example, if I click "Info", the message will pop out. But to close this message, I'll have to click on the toggle on the right. What I want to achieve is when I click "Info" for the second time, the messages will disappear. And if I click again after that, it will appear again. That means the button works like a switch to control the message.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: If you take a look at the displayed message using firebug for example, you can see there is a `$(this).parent().slideUp();return false;` function when the toogle is clicked. So replacing `parent()` by your current component id should work.

Comment: I think that's for how the message appears?...

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here, at toogle function:
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/